# php Class initialisation in the same page

Tags: php, oop

If this was put on hold because the answers will be opinion oriented and not fact, well, opinion of the experts was what I was looking for. Where else will a developer get opinions on issues that's not generic if not on stackoverflow. If it's put on hold or close is OK!

Like I said I put out the question because I knew it wasn't conventional and I wanted to know the implications and I got good people and experts told me it was a bad idea and that was all I needed.

Again thank you guys for your time.

---

I like initializing my class in the same class page, then require the page each time I need the class. my question is should I be worried or I am good? 
Thanks for your answers

// in class.php

```
class Product{
//some methods
}

$product = New Product;

?>



//in product.php 
<?php
require_once (class.php);
$product->someMethods();

?>
```

Comment: I would recommend against it. Especially when you come to use `__construct` functions, allowing you to have multiple instances of your class for different uses. If you want to do it like this, I'd recommend creating `interfaces` and create classes from that

Comment: it really depends on what `Product` class does. But just to be safe, i'd recommend against it especially when the functions of `Product` expands and you need to keep the structure intact.

Comment: Technically your code works. But i would discourage you to do this for sake of programming ethnics. For you it may be ok, but once you start to make project with 2 or more people, this can be frustrating for them.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I know I could write it like this:

<?php
require_once(class.php);
$product = new Product();
$product->someMethods();

?>

and I know it is unconventional which is why I was scared it could cause serious issue later on. Thank you all now I know better

Answer (score 1):

This approach looks like anti-pattern and uncommon for php world (regardless fact that it works).

It's better to do next:

```
//in product.php 
<?php
require_once(class.php);
$product = new Product();
$product->someMethods();
```

This approach wide spreaded in php world moreover your `class.php` contains only code related to class - it's clear and simple.

But,

if you really need to have only one product class instance - it makes sense to use singleton design pattern, you can find simple example [here](https://github.com/cn007b/my/blob/master/ed/php/patterns/1.singleton.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I write your way, I just started this unconventional way on the project I'm currently working on but I suspect it could be bad which is why I asked the question. Thank you.